# c++ version of Python's os module

Tags: python, c++, module

what is the c++ module equivalent of Python's "import os"?

Any time I try to google "c++ version of python os", it shows me how to get the operating system version in either python or c++.

Comment: It's usually the API of the OS. It depends on the OS how to access it. The C++ standard doesn't know what an operating system is. It doesn't have libraries for this kind of functionality.

Comment: There isn't a direct equivalent, what are you trying to do?

Comment: what do you mean by the API of the os? Does that mean that it's already 'included', or do I have to #include <what you're talking about>? Either way, what methods are there, and is python better for file navigation and manipulation?

Comment: You have to include the headers. _"is python better for file navigation and manipulation"_. This depends. Modern C++ is very similar to Python regarding filesystem (but that's not OS-related in C++). But with C++ you have access to C functions and C functions are much more low level.

Comment: I'm trying to do some weird file navigation and management in python, but I like c++ a lot more than python, and was wondering if I can navigate through files in c++ as easy (or at all) as I could in python.

Comment: say I have a file "C:\folderx\foldery\filez"

I'm trying to take that string and return it, but indexed:
"main-23-24-25"

Comment: C++17 has filesystem library. You can use it for such operations. Before C++17 you could use boost filesystem or the OS API, e.g. for Linux it's dirent.h

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a direct equivalent in C++, but you can achieve same things by other means. For example, `<filesystem>` header has functionality to work with paths, some OS-specific headers like `<Windows.h>` have more functionality at the cost of being non-portable and so on. Depends on what you want to do.